# masking hair/feathers photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, mask, clipping-mask, blend-modes

I'm following a tutorial for cutting out hair from a background and applying it to this photo of a parrot and cutting around its feather.

So far through following the tutorial I have...

- Selected and duplicated the channel (RGB) with the highest contrast
- Adjusted levels to increase contrast
- Made selection and created a mask from image
- Alt+click on a mask to refine the selection using the brush tool
- Created a new background layer and filled white
- Created a new layer above the parrot image layer and made a clipping mask.
- Switched the blending mode to darken.

The final step on the tutorial is to use the clone tool while on the clipping mask layer and sample the color of the hair and brush over to remove the white parts around the hair.

[image]

However, my image originally had a black background and nothing seems to be happening. I tried changing blending modes but nothing seems to be affected. I am thinking the black background has something to do with it but not sure what to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Masking out hair/feathers photoshop CS6](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/154345/masking-out-hair-feathers-photoshop-cs6)

Comment: @Rafael that was a duplicate of my post I have deleted it now

Comment: I don't really follow.. it looks like you have some sort of drop shadow or blur applied to the edges.

Comment: I think I've just realised what I've done. When creating a new clipping layer for the darken blending mode and to use the cloning tool I wasn't sampling the image I was just clicking on the empty layer above >_<. I seems to work now

Comment: So is this question solved?